# Dynamically added option in SelectOneMenu control on a JSF form submits as null

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish

I have a standard JSF h:form which contains an h:SelectOneMenu control.  As long as I am selecting an item from the list which is populated when the page is rendered it works perfectly.  I don't think it is important, but to put it in context, the value from the select is used to build a query which returns a list of matching records.

I've implemented the JQuery autocomplete box on the control and it still works just fine as long as I'm selecting one of the original values.

The problem comes when I enter a value not in the select control when the page is rendered.  Using JQuery, I've set it up so that when a value not on the list entered, the value is added to the select as a new option.

I can verify that the option is added to the underlying select control, and selected through the javascript.  However when the setter is invoked in the backing bean immediately after that, the value passed in to the setter is null, and the function to run the query is never reached.  The following error is returned in the AJAX response, but I have yet to be able to find a place where the value is validated.  It isn't a required field either.

> Validation Error: Value is not valid

Here is my front end code:

```
   <h:selectOneMenu id="make" styleClass="combobox" value="#{listBean.make}" 
                     effect="fade" label="#{listBean.makeLabel}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{listBean.makeList}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

And the setter in the bean:

```
    public void setMake(String make) {
       this.make = make;
    }
```

I'm guessing I just need to find a way to include the new option in the makeList List on the backing bean, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Java EE 6, GlassFish 3.1, Eclipse 3.7 - problem observed on both FireFox and Chrome

Comment: It's a List<SelectItem> which contains an ArrayList of SelectItems

Comment: I have not used SelectItem (I already pass the bean). Could you make the value `make` be a SelectItem too?

Comment: Doesn't look like that will work...Conversion Error setting value 'Acme' for 'null Converter. 

I entered 'Acme' as the new value. The existing values don't work with that either.

Comment: Sorry, thought about it, I don't think it will be the issue. Got the same error in my projects, but as I said I used directly beans. That meant I had to specify a Converter so, when the value was passed to the backing bean, it could convert the String passed from the select as a parameter in the HTTP request back to a valid bean. Being that `make` is already a String, that should not be necessary. I cannot help anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the dynamically added item through `<f:selectItems>`, not through JavaScript. If the item is not present in `<f:selectItems>`, then you will get exactly this validation error. This is done so as part of safeguard against tampered/hacked requests in an attempt to get illegal/unprovided values into the server side.

Easier is to use a JSF component library. PrimeFaces for example has a [`<p:autoComplete>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf) for the exact purpose.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping to get, but at least now I know why I couldn't get it to work.  Thanks!